# Escrever apenas uma linha no BufferedWriter

Tags: java

Bom, eu tenho um arquivo de texto com algumas linhas, para vocês entenderem melhor, aqui está o que eu tenho nesse arquivo:

```
0    
Zombie+160+-50    
Zombie+160+290    
Robot+-50+120    
Spider+370+120    
doors    
1+BossRoom1    
3+Loja1
```

Basicamente, eu quero mudar aquele 0 para 1 enquanto o programa roda, o que eu fiz então é usar um BufferedWriter e um FileWriter, porém quando eu coloco o código:

```
bw.write("1");
```

Ele apaga todo o conteudo do meu arquivo e deixa apenas com esse 1 no vazio, existe alguma maneira que alterar apenas algumas linhas, não só a primeira, mas outras também, caso eu tenha que alterar alguma outra linha futuramente?

Linha completa de gravação para vocês verem como eu fiz:

```
File file = new File("resources/Save/Room1.txt");

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write("1");
    bw.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa de um [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

```
File file = new File("resources/Save/Room1.txt");
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
raf.seek(0l);
raf.writeChars("1");
// Não se esqueça de tratar exceções, fechar recursos, etc
```

A classe `RandomAcessFile` possui tudo o que você precisa para navegar dentro de um arquivo, bem como ler e manipular partes dele (seja de forma binária ou textual). Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados no Javadoc.

Tenha em mente porém que se você pretende modificar o tamanho do arquivo (e.g., substituir uma linha por outra maior ou menor) pode ser mais fácil reescrever o arquivo inteiro do que tentar manipulá-lo.

---

Caso você queira utilizar algo mais novo, a API NIO.2 introduziu o [`SeekableByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html) com funcionalidades similares de posicionamento. Você pode encontrar [um exemplo no Tutorial Oficial da Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html).